# Reduce array in javascript with patern matching

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would you reduce items from array `arr` into `reducedArray` by removing items that first two characters match with strings from array `generalCase` and if they encountered, then an asterisk is added to indicated that this string was encountered on array `arr`.

```js
let arr =["ADB", "AB1", "BD1", "BD4", "AB3", "BP9", "BPX","STR", "ABS"]
let generalCase = ["AB", "BD", "BP"]
let reducedArray = []

arr.forEach( item => {
  if (item.startsWith("AB") && !reducedArray.includes("AB*")) {
        reducedArray.push("AB*");
      } else if (item.startsWith("BD") && !reducedArray.includes("BD*")) {
        reducedArray.push("BD*")
      } else if (item.startsWith("BP") && !reducedArray.includes("BP*")) {
        reducedArray.push("BP*")
      } else if (item === "STR") {
        reducedArray.push("STR")
      } else if (!reducedArray.includes(item)) {
        reducedArray.push(item)
      }
})

// Desired result: ["ADB", "AB*", "BD*", "BP*", "STR"]
console.log(reducedArray) // ["ADB", "AB*", "BD*", "BD4", "AB3", "BP*", "BPX", "STR", "ABS"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = ["ADB", "AB1", "BD1", "BD4", "AB3", "BP9", "BPX","STR", "ABS"];
const generalCase = ["AB", "BD", "BP"];

const reducedArray = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    const firsttwo = c.substring(0,2);
    const toPush = (generalCase.includes(firsttwo)) ? (firsttwo + '*') : c;
    
    if (!p.includes(toPush)) {
        p.push(toPush);
    }
    
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(reducedArray);
```

#### Result:

```json
[
  "ADB",
  "AB*",
  "BD*",
  "BP*",
  "STR"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a regex from the `generalCase` array to `test` if any of the strings in `arr` start with any of them.

In this case, it creates a regex like this:

```
/^(?:AB|BD|BP)/
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const arr = ["ADB", "AB1", "BD1", "BD4", "AB3", "BP9", "BPX", "STR", "ABS"],
      generalCase = ["AB", "BD", "BP"],
      regex = new RegExp(`^(?:${generalCase.join("|")})`),
      set = new Set;

for (const str of arr) {
  if (regex.test(str))
    set.add(str.slice(0, 2) + "*")
  else
    set.add(str)
}

console.log([...set])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate normally, and deduplicate the result in the end:

```js
let arr =["ADB", "AB1", "BD1", "BD4", "AB3", "BP9", "BPX","STR", "ABS"]
let generalCase = ["AB", "BD", "BP"]

let reducedArray = arr.map(item => {
    for (let x of generalCase)
        if (item.startsWith(x))
            return x + '*'
    return item
})


reducedArray = [...new Set(reducedArray)]

console.log(reducedArray)
```